# Ajax, filter div by id.

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have problem with filter more identic id in the same page.

```
document.getElementById(val1).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

I have three the same `<div id="name"></div>` on one page. And only first div display content. I try with jQuery and filter... but I dont have progress.

Comment: That's because ID's should be unique.

Comment: Ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id selector is something to return one unique element (or none if not found). That's why you shouldn't use multiple ids - it will always return [at most] only one (the first).

Fix that fault by using classes or something.

If you really have to get multiple elements with the same id, you can do by using an attribute selector:

```
$('[id="name"]').html(xmlhttp.responseText);
// or
[].forEach(document.querySelectorAll('[id="name"]'), function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById
```

return only first element that having the specified `ID`. `Id` should always be unique.
You can try with other attributes like `class` and then use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")
```

that will return all the elements of given class.

Answer (score 0):

`id`s should be unique.  You shouldn't have two or more elements on the same page with the same id.  You can use class names to identify them, and those can definitely be the same.  I don't know your code, but try using `document.getElementsByClassName` (not supported in IE8), or using jQuery to simplify what you are trying to do: `$('.my_class_name').html(xmlhttp.responseText)`

Comment: Yeah, it works exactly what i want. But i will change code if ids should be unique